# Passenger rights payment for delay caused by extraordinary circumstances on another flight?

Tags: europe, delays, passenger-rights

My long-distance flight (>3500km) with an EU airline (Lufthansa) is delayed for ~6 hours. At checkin they told me they had to re-route due to medical issues.

From what I found online, a medical emergency may qualify as extraordinary reasons but e.g. a delay caused by bad weather (another extraordinary reason) on the flight that brings the plan to the departure airport doesn't.

Does the same apply to medical reasons on a previous flight?

Details:

- LH 454 from FRA to SFO had to re-route to Iceland, apparently due to a medical emergency.
- This is the same plane as LH 455 from SFO to FRA, for which I have a ticket, and which is delayed by ~6 hours.
- While this most likely means extraordinary circumstances for LH 454 passengers, I'm not sure whether or not it's considered extraordinary circumstances for my LH 455 flight.

Comment: I imagine they will claim a medical diversion is an 'extraordinary circumstance' that is beyond their control, thus denying any compensation.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the IACA [pleading for a change of regulation](http://www.iaca.be/php/issues/index.php?doc_id=3620)

> IACA members see the following key priorities for their business model:
>
> an acknowledgement that airlines must optimise the use of their fleet and that reactionary (sequential) delays should therefore be taken into account in the exemptions to pay out compensation. Indeed, a flight irregularity often creates knock-on effects, i.e. impacts more than one aircraft rotation.

It is quite clear currently this is not so otherwise why would they want a change?

Comment: So I guess I should be entitled to compensation?

Comment: That is my interpretation, yes. Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and I do not even play one on television.

Comment: I think their issue is that the effect of a delayed flight can effect several subsequent flights rather than just the immediate flight.

Comment: Which is exactly OP's case.